# Japanese homestay gifts?

Tags: japan, study, gifts

I am an American and I will be going to Japan for a study abroad program to Japan. I will be having 3 host families. I want to give gifts to my host Families and I am having trouble coming up with ideas  do you have any ideas. what are some ideas you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be anything elaborate, but something typically American will be appreciated. If you are from a rural region, some local products will be nice, otherwise just get something from a souvenir shop at the airport before you leave, and don't worry about the kitsch. If you want to make it personal, add a box of your favourite candy. (Candy is always ok, even if the family doesn't have children.)